# ZF2 tutorial Album PHPUnit test failing with Undefined property: AlbumTest\Model\AlbumTableTest::$controller

Tags: php, phpunit, zend-framework2

I am building the ZF2 Album tutorial application and when I unit test I am consistently receiving the same error even though I've rebuilt the application again.  Can someone tell me what is going on here?  I am dumping all relevant information here to assist.  The error is:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\test\phpunit.xml.dist

......E

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 6.25Mb

There was 1 error:

1) AlbumTest\Model\AlbumTableTest::testGetAlbumTableReturnsAnInstanceOfAlbumTable
Undefined property: AlbumTest\Model\AlbumTableTest::$controller

D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\test\AlbumTest\Model\AlbumTableTest.php:116

FAILURES!
Tests: 7, Assertions: 9, Errors: 1.
```

AlbumTableTest.php is as follows and the error is received on the final assertion:

```
<?php

namespace AlbumTest\Model;

use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
use Album\Model\Album;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;

class AlbumTableTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testFetchAllReturnsAllAlbums() {
        $resultSet = new ResultSet();
        $mockTableGateway = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway', array('select'), array(), '', false);
        $mockTableGateway->expects($this->once())
                ->method('select')
                ->with()
                ->will($this->returnValue($resultSet));

        $albumTable = new AlbumTable($mockTableGateway);

        $this->assertSame($resultSet, $albumTable->fetchAll());
    }

    public function testCanRetrieveAnAlbumByItsId() {
        $album = new Album();
        $album->exchangeArray(array('id' => 123,
            'artist' => 'The Military Wives',
            'title' => 'In My Dreams'));

        $resultSet = new ResultSet();
        $resultSet->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
        $resultSet->initialize(array($album));

        $mockTableGateway = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway', array('select'), array(), '', false);
        $mockTableGateway->expects($this->once())
                ->method('select')
                ->with(array('id' => 123))
                ->will($this->returnValue($resultSet));

        $albumTable = new AlbumTable($mockTableGateway);

        $this->assertSame($album, $albumTable->getAlbum(123));
    }

    public function testCanDeleteAnAlbumByItsId() {
        $mockTableGateway = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway', array('delete'), array(), '', false);
        $mockTableGateway->expects($this->once())
                ->method('delete')
                ->with(array('id' => 123));

        $albumTable = new AlbumTable($mockTableGateway);
        $albumTable->deleteAlbum(123);
    }

    public function testSaveAlbumWillInsertNewAlbumsIfTheyDontAlreadyHaveAnId() {
        $albumData = array('artist' => 'The Military Wives', 'title' => 'In My Dreams');
        $album = new Album();
        $album->exchangeArray($albumData);

        $mockTableGateway = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway', array('insert'), array(), '', false);
        $mockTableGateway->expects($this->once())
                ->method('insert')
                ->with($albumData);

        $albumTable = new AlbumTable($mockTableGateway);
        $albumTable->saveAlbum($album);
    }

    public function testSaveAlbumWillUpdateExistingAlbumsIfTheyAlreadyHaveAnId() {
        $albumData = array('id' => 123, 'artist' => 'The Military Wives', 'title' => 'In My Dreams');
        $album = new Album();
        $album->exchangeArray($albumData);

        $resultSet = new ResultSet();
        $resultSet->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
        $resultSet->initialize(array($album));

        $mockTableGateway = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway', array('select', 'update'), array(), '', false);
        $mockTableGateway->expects($this->once())
                ->method('select')
                ->with(array('id' => 123))
                ->will($this->returnValue($resultSet));
        $mockTableGateway->expects($this->once())
                ->method('update')
                ->with(array('artist' => 'The Military Wives', 'title' => 'In My Dreams'), array('id' => 123));

        $albumTable = new AlbumTable($mockTableGateway);
        $albumTable->saveAlbum($album);
    }

    public function testExceptionIsThrownWhenGettingNonexistentAlbum() {
        $resultSet = new ResultSet();
        $resultSet->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
        $resultSet->initialize(array());

        $mockTableGateway = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway', array('select'), array(), '', false);
        $mockTableGateway->expects($this->once())
                ->method('select')
                ->with(array('id' => 123))
                ->will($this->returnValue($resultSet));

        $albumTable = new AlbumTable($mockTableGateway);

        try {
            $albumTable->getAlbum(123);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->assertSame('Could not find row 123', $e->getMessage());
            return;
        }

        $this->fail('Expected exception was not thrown');
    }

    public function testGetAlbumTableReturnsAnInstanceOfAlbumTable() {
        $this->assertInstanceOf('Album\Model\AlbumTable', $this->controller->getAlbumTable());
    }

}

?>
```

getAlbumTable is in AlbumController as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Album\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController {

    protected $albumTable;

    public function indexAction() {
        return new ViewModel(array(
                    'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),
                ));
    }

    public function addAction() {

    }

    public function editAction() {

    }

    public function deleteAction() {

    }

    public function getAlbumTable() {
        if (!$this->albumTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->albumTable = $sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');
        }
        return $this->albumTable;
    }

}

?>
```

And AlbumTable is:

```
<?php
namespace Album\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class AlbumTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
        return $resultSet;
    }

    public function getAlbum($id)
    {
        $id  = (int) $id;
        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (!$row) {
            throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
        }
        return $row;
    }

    public function saveAlbum(Album $album)
    {
        $data = array(
            'artist' => $album->artist,
            'title'  => $album->title,
        );

        $id = (int)$album->id;
        if ($id == 0) {
            $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
        } else {
            if ($this->getAlbum($id)) {
                $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('Form id does not exist');
            }
        }
    }

    public function deleteAlbum($id)
    {
        $this->tableGateway->delete(array('id' => $id));
    }
}
?>
```

Module.php is:

```
<?php
namespace Album;

class Module
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
    // Add this method:
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                    $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                    return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
?>
```

module.config.php is:

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
        ),
    ),

    // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

application.config.php is:

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Album',                  // <-- Add this line
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

Bootstrap.php:

```
<?php
namespace AlbumTest;//Change this namespace for your test

use Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory;
use Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use RuntimeException;

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
chdir(__DIR__);

class Bootstrap
{
    protected static $serviceManager;
    protected static $config;
    protected static $bootstrap;

    public static function init()
    {
        // Load the user-defined test configuration file, if it exists; otherwise, load
        if (is_readable(__DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php')) {
            $testConfig = include __DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php';
        } else {
            $testConfig = include __DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php.dist';
        }

        $zf2ModulePaths = array();

        if (isset($testConfig['module_listener_options']['module_paths'])) {
            $modulePaths = $testConfig['module_listener_options']['module_paths'];
            foreach ($modulePaths as $modulePath) {
                if (($path = static::findParentPath($modulePath)) ) {
                    $zf2ModulePaths[] = $path;
                }
            }
        }

        $zf2ModulePaths  = implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $zf2ModulePaths) . PATH_SEPARATOR;
        $zf2ModulePaths .= getenv('ZF2_MODULES_TEST_PATHS') ?: (defined('ZF2_MODULES_TEST_PATHS') ? ZF2_MODULES_TEST_PATHS : '');

        static::initAutoloader();

        // use ModuleManager to load this module and it's dependencies
        $baseConfig = array(
            'module_listener_options' => array(
                'module_paths' => explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $zf2ModulePaths),
            ),
        );

        $config = ArrayUtils::merge($baseConfig, $testConfig);

        $serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
        $serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $config);
        $serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();

        static::$serviceManager = $serviceManager;
        static::$config = $config;
    }

    public static function getServiceManager()
    {
        return static::$serviceManager;
    }

    public static function getConfig()
    {
        return static::$config;
    }

    protected static function initAutoloader()
    {
        $vendorPath = static::findParentPath('vendor');

        if (is_readable($vendorPath . '/autoload.php')) {
            $loader = include $vendorPath . '/autoload.php';
        } else {
            $zf2Path = getenv('ZF2_PATH') ?: (defined('ZF2_PATH') ? ZF2_PATH : (is_dir($vendorPath . '/ZF2/library') ? $vendorPath . '/ZF2/library' : false));

            if (!$zf2Path) {
                throw new RuntimeException('Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.');
            }

            include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';

        }

        AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'autoregister_zf' => true,
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        ));
    }

    protected static function findParentPath($path)
    {
        $dir = __DIR__;
        $previousDir = '.';
        while (!is_dir($dir . '/' . $path)) {
            $dir = dirname($dir);
            if ($previousDir === $dir) return false;
            $previousDir = $dir;
        }
        return $dir . '/' . $path;
    }
}

Bootstrap::init();
?>
```

TestConfig.php.dist:

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Album',
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            '../../../config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            'module',
            'vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

And, finally, phpunit.xml.dist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<phpunit bootstrap="Bootstrap.php"> 
    <testsuites> 
        <testsuite name="zf2tutorial"> 
            <directory>./AlbumTest</directory> 
        </testsuite> 
    </testsuites> 
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am not certain that this is the appropriate fix at this point, I resolved the error.  I looked into AlbumControllerTest as opposed to AlbumTableTest.  It has a setup method that creates the controller class.  I copied the setup code along with the appropriate use statements and variable declarations and, for the moment, I am on to the next issue...

I'm still interested in a better answer!

What I copied (added) includes:

```
use AlbumTest\Bootstrap;
use Album\Controller\AlbumController;
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Http\Response;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack as HttpRouter;
use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;


class AlbumTableTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    protected $controller;
    protected $request;
    protected $response;
    protected $routeMatch;
    protected $event;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $serviceManager = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();
        $this->controller = new AlbumController();
        $this->request    = new Request();
        $this->routeMatch = new RouteMatch(array('controller' => 'index'));
        $this->event      = new MvcEvent();
        $config = $serviceManager->get('Config');
        $routerConfig = isset($config['router']) ? $config['router'] : array();
        $router = HttpRouter::factory($routerConfig);
        $this->event->setRouter($router);
        $this->event->setRouteMatch($this->routeMatch);
        $this->controller->setEvent($this->event);
        $this->controller->setServiceLocator($serviceManager);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct to assume that you need to add some setup code and comparing it with `AlbumControllerTest.php` is a good idea.

As the error message states, the issue is that the `AlbumTableTest` object does not have     `controller` property.  We therefore need to add the property using:

```
$protected controller
```

and initialise it using:

```
$this->controller = new AlbumController()
```

In addition, we need to initialise the `serviceManager` property and set its `serviceLocator` property so that the following calls make sense in the `getAlbumTable` method of the controller:

```
$sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
$this->albumTable = $sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');
```

To summarise, you did the right thing but you didn't need all the additional code.  You can get away with:

```
use AlbumTest\Bootstrap;
use Album\Controller\AlbumController;
use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
use Album\Model\Album;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase; 


class AlbumTableTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase       
{                                                             
protected $controller; 


    protected function setUp()
    {   
        $serviceManager = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();
        $this->controller = new AlbumController();  
        $this->controller->setServiceLocator($serviceManager);
    }

....
```

at the start of `AlbumTableTest.php`

Comment: Thank you for that information.  It certainly fits.  I assumed I could trim it down but you did it best.  I am glad I was at least doing the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the new import statements in Module.php. The start of the file should look like this:

```
namespace Album;

use Album\Model\Album;
use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class Module
{
 //...
```

Easy to skip, hard to find, I've spent good 15 minutes on the same thing...